# Zend Studio SVN -- how do I tell if a file is locked by another user?

Tags: php, svn, zend-studio

Does anyone know how to tell if a file is currently locked by another user in svn using the Zend Studio IDE?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the svn:needs-lock property on files that really require locking. That way the files will be read-only on disk. The way to make them writable is locking the file. When you lock a file that has been locked by another user, you'll be notified of that.

There's usually no need to know what files are locked, until you want to take a lock on the same file